# Editing properties of a PictureBox from another class

Tags: c#, winforms, picturebox

Context: I am trying to make a little game of Backgammon in Windows.Forms. I have 3 classes GameBoard.cs, Points.cs and Checkers.cs (as well as Form1.cs). What I need to be able to do is change values of some properties of a PictureBox using some of my other classes.

Specifically I have this code:

```
// gameBoard.cs

namespace backgammon
{
    public class gameBoard
    {

        Checker checker1;
        Points point1;
        Points[] pointsArray;

        public gameBoard()
        {
             // make new checker (ID, PictureBox, startingPoint)
             checker1 = new Checker(1, checkerPicBox1, 1);

             // make new Point (ID, arrayOfCheckers)
             point13 = new Points(1, new Checker[]{checker1 /*,checker2... etc*/});

             pointsArray = new Points[MAX_POINTS];
             pointsArray[0] = point1;
        }
    }
}
```

so this is how I have "setup" the checkers and points. My checker and point classes can get and set on all variables that were passed into its construction.

Problem: what I am trying to achieve is to "highlight" a checker once it is clicked.

In Form1:

```
// Form1.cs

private void checkerPicBox1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int pointNumber = gameBoard.checker1.getPointMember();

    // find the top most checker in the checker array so we can highlight it 
    Checker topMost = gameBoard.pointsArray[pointNumber - 1].getCheckerFromIndex(gameBoard.pointsArray[pointNumber - 1].getCheckerArray().Length - 1);

    // get the picturebox and change the image
    topMost.getPictureBox().BackgroundImage = global::Backgammon.Properties.Resources.blackCheckerSelected;
}
```

The code compiles and runs but when it gets to the last line of checkerPicBox_Click nothing seems to happen (the image doesn't change).

What is happening here? Do I not have the correct instance of my PictureBox? Or am I doing this in a weird way/not the way i'm supposed to be?

Comment: What pictureBox are you getting with `getPictureBox()`? Is it equal to `null`?

Comment: In this example (the only checker in the checker array i'm searching in is `checker1`) so it would be getting the `PictureBox` assosiated with `checker1`

EDIT - No, the `getPictureBox()` doesn't return null.

Comment: `topMost.getPictureBox().BackgroundImage = null;` does this code empty the pictureBox? Another thing, you are using variable `i`, where is it declared?

Comment: You might have to call `topmost.getPictureBox().Refresh()`

Comment: @DonBoitnott Or `topmost.getPictureBox().Invalidate();`

Comment: @MaxMommersteeg It doesn't. This is the issue - I can't edit or change any of the values or properties once I have "got" the `PictureBox`. I can see that all the values are correct, like the width, height and image are all what I initially set them as. Opps `i` is supposed to be `pointNumber` i copied it directly from my project.

Comment: @sday03 Did you try using Invalidate() or Refresh() after updating BackgroundImage?

Comment: I have tried both as well as `update()` and none have worked so far.

Answer (score 0):

Since the checkers are connected to the pictureboxes, why not create a new reference property for them in the Checker class?

You could pass the form containing the pictureboxes in the constructor, and use the form to create your references to the right picturebox instances.

```
// gameBoard.cs

namespace backgammon
{
    public class gameBoard
    {
        Checker checker1;
        Points point1;
        Points[] pointsArray;

        public gameBoard(Form gameForm)
        {
             // make new checker (ID, PictureBox, startingPoint)
             checker1 = new Checker(1, gameForm.checkerPicBox1, 1);

             // make new Point (ID, arrayOfCheckers)
             point13 = new Points(1, new Checker[]{checker1 /*,checker2... etc*/});

             pointsArray = new Points[MAX_POINTS];
             pointsArray[0] = point1;
        }
    }
}
```

Add the picturebox property to your Checker class:

```
// checker.cs

public class Checker
{
   PictureBox _picturebox;

   //... other code here

   public Checker(int ID, PictureBox picturebox, Points startingPoint)
   {
      _picturebox = picturebox;

      //...other code here
   }
}
```

Then we can use this in the game form:

```
gameBoard gameBoard1 = new gameBoard(this);
gameBoard1.checker1._picturebox.BackgroundImage = global::Backgammon.Properties.Resources.blackCheckerSelected;
gameBoard1.checker1._picturebox.Invalidate();
```